# Who becomes user 1 on a new site?

Tags: support, users, beta-sites

I joined the private beta of 3Dprinting.SE today and while editing my profile I noticed that my user number (not sure what it's called) was fairly low.

I wondered if there's a user 1 and indeed there is: it's [Robert Cartaino ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino). I would think that maybe he [proposed the site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing), but that's not the case.

Out of curiosity: who becomes user 1 on a newly created site of the SE network?

Comment: Whoever signs up first.

Comment: @Doorknob No... It's always a SE staff member. It's probably whoever "activates" the site... since Robert's one of the main Area 51 Admins, it makes sense he's user 1

Comment: @Catija We sign up as well.

Comment: @bluefeet sure... but it makes sense that it would be someone "testing" the site... Geoff Dalgas is user 1 or 2 on a lot of sites.

Comment: Sometimes, [nobody](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/1)!

Comment: @JeremyBanks well, it's not very surprising that nobody wants to be the first at the workplace =)

Comment: @Catija Not always. http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1/undo

Comment: There's also a User -1. Just to boggle your mind. (Hint, it's the Community User)

Comment: Usually it's me. (I set up the sites and join to make sure everything is working correctly.)

Comment: @AdamLear thank you for doing that!

Comment: @AdamLear On sites without a user 1, have you deleted your account there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the first user to join the site gets ID 1.

It's usually a Stack Exchange employee (a developer or a community manager, typically) because they create the site and so visit it and poke around to make sure that everything is in order.

The Community user, however, is user -1 everywhere, so the robots always get there first!

Comment: Can there be a user 0?

Comment: @sumelic Nope, but there is a User -1

Comment: [Not always an SE employee though.](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1/undo)

Comment: @Andy Yeahhhh... that was when I rolled out new login UI and forgot to put a private beta gate in. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AdamLear Actually, I think I got that by faking the Area 51 visit link. I don't remember it giving me a login UI right off the bat. I had the hardwarerecs domain on a browser tab that I'd refresh occasionally to see how low a user ID I could get. Turns out it's pretty low.

Comment: @Adam so that's the only case?

Comment: @Undo That'd probably do it too, yeah. I forget how that link works off the top of my head.

Comment: @Undo I looked at the code, and it looks like the /visit link only works for proposals that A51 considered to be in beta already. I'll test it out properly next time we're about to launch a site.

Answer (score 7):

It is always the first one to sign up, usually the Community Managers or some type of employee at SE as they would usually know when a site gets to beta firsthand.

Of course, Community would take the spot for first user as its id is actually -1. Also, there is also no user ID of 0: https://stackoverflow.com/users/0